# How to Verify DEBUG flag using c#

Tags: c#

My scenario is,if Application is in debug mode then certain action will trigger ,but for this first i have to verify the state of Debugger pragmatically,so is there any method or c# library to do this

Comment: Web project or windows app?

Answer (score 2):

If debugger is attached then it will return true.

```
  if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a web application, use `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled`

For a windows application, use the `DEBUG` flag during compilation and discriminate in your code using the [If directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)